# How to call a method which populates bean, When I press a anchor tag with help of c:url

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

I have a JSP page (home page) in a Web App, which has different anchor tags (like home, video, pictures, profile etc) for navigation in a Web App.

For, **anchor tags** I am using JSTL tag (**c:url**)

#### The Process:

1. I am on home page and press a anchor tag (like profile).
2. Anchor tag, which uses c:url tag of JSTL redirects it to profile page.
3. The profile page gets displayed with user information

#### The code that I am using in JSP:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/profile.jsp" />" >Profile</a>
```

#### What I want?

1. When anchor tag (profile page) is pressed on the home page, a method should be
   called to fetch the user details from database and populate it in appropriate 
   bean So that it can be accessed in that profile page using Expression Language
2. Is the above question/or method right to do so? If no, then Which process is 
   better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the method you describe is a good start. However, to do the database part it might be better to look at using a Servlet. So you create a Servlet class that implements the doGet() method.

You have to create a mapping for your servlet in the web.xml file, so assume that you map the url: /profile to the servlet that you create then the link will be:

```
  <a href="<c:url value="/profile" />" >Profile</a>
```

In that method you interact with your database, populate your bean and save it in the request scope. Next, you forward to the jsp page that will display the bean data.

On the jsp page the bean will be available for you to display the data.

Comment: I understood the concept you are saying. But now my doubt is, Will url mentioned in value part of c:url, map it with Servlet internally with help of DD in same one Request?

Comment: yes. THat's the idea. Once you map the servlet to a url in web.xml then you can specify the url in the link and invoke the servlet

Comment: Note that the `<c:url>` is not necessary here. You can do as good without it `<a href="profile">`. The only benefit it adds is that it automatically prepends the context path whenever necessary.

Comment: I am getting following Exception: Exception in thread ""http-bio-8080"-exec-6" java.lang.StackOverflowError. What does this exactly mean? For a moment I thought, How could Stackoverflow site can cause error. :):)

Comment: Stackoverflow is usually caused by some infinite loop in your program, maybe a circular reference.